# Getting Positional arguments error in selenium python when trying to read json

Tags: python, selenium

I am not able to read json in selenium python
No matter whatever I do It always throw an error.
TypeError: Login.test_login() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'username' and 'pwd'
Can someone please help on this.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
from ddt import file_data


class Login:
@file_data('../testdata/login.json')
def test_login(self, username, pwd):

    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get('http://privacy.evidonstage.com/v3/sitenotice/manage')
    email = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'EmailAddress')
    email.clear()
    email.send_keys(username)
    password = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'Password')
    password.clear()
    password.send_keys(pwd)
    btn_submit = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[id="SignIn"]')
    btn_submit.click()
    time.sleep(5)

def test_logout(self):
    username = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'userLabel')
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(username).perform()
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        logout = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(text(),"Sign out")]')))
        logout.click()
        time.sleep(3)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

login.json

```
{"username": "test@test.com",
"password": "test123"}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of json file?

Comment: {
  "username": "test@test.com",
  "password": "test123"
}
The question is why the error is thrown missing 2 required positional arguments

Comment: You should initialize and close your driver whithin a fixture.

Comment: Could you add a more complete traceback? line numbers etc...

Comment: Where is the decorator `file_data` exported from: Is it a plugin or some custom code because this is what you need to have a look at.

Comment: file_data is a built-in utility in pythin to read json data

Comment: No, it is not a builtin it is a package: https://pypi.org/project/ddt/

Comment: Also: 1. The tests won't run since the class does not start with `Test` 2. The fixtures username and pw are not defined 3. The indentation is wrong